# Stop reloading of table data in UITableView when it pulls/scrolls

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I know it is not general practice to do this but my application need this functionality. I am very new to iPhone programming. When the user pulls/scrolls the table screen it gets updated I have to stop it. Also order of the data get changed when I pull it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(optionButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:optionValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTag:indexPath.row];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    [button release];
}
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Please show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Also, tell us why you don't want to update the the table rows. If you do things right it should not cause any problems.

Comment: I have updated the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath method. All the data coming in these cells is from database. And I don't want to reload data again and again when the user scrolls it. When Data is refreshed order of the data get changes i don't want it.

Answer (score -1):

First, the way you are using cellForRowAtIndexPath is wrong.

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(optionButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    [button release];
}
//These should be outside of the cell == nil loop so that they get refreshed correctly
[button setTitle:optionValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTag:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

Secondly, I don't see where you set optionValue, but if you don't want to hit the database every time, then store the values in an NSArray and get the values from the array. This way you only hit the database once when you load the view.

Comment: I have removed code which set the optionValue from above method. Now everything working fine when i removed the line if(cell == nil). I using NSMutable array and I am not hitting the database every time  thanks.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work i.e. doesn't refresh the cells correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Tell me more information and I might be able to help. How does it fail?

Comment: I tried the above code, first time it works well. but when I scrolls the table cell, order of the cells get changed. Some cells are duplicated and some cells are not displayed. But when I remove the if condition my code everything is working fine. Is it right way of coding or not. Since I am not much familiar with iPhone programming please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is how you are setting optionValue. But I don't know for sure because you haven't shown me how are you doing that.

Comment: I am setting optionValue from the NSMutableArray